How do I get to fastboot after uploading some kind of broken firmware with fastboot?
I messed up and destroyed vendor_boot.img by overwriting it with boot.img and now the phone won't boot even to fastboot.
It responds to USB device enumeration as 18D1:4F00 Google Inc. Pixel ROM Recovery
How do I get back to fastboot?
